# Levenberg-Marquardt for root-finding: just square the function?

Tags: optimization, rootfinding

This question might be so obvious and trivial that I'm having a hard time googling it.

I have a multivariate root finding problem that I'm trying to solve in C# and the library that I'm trying to use is alglib.  That package doesn't have any dedicated root solvers in it, but has Levenberg-Marquardt.  To do root finding, do I just take the squared vector result and feed it to the LM solver?  Then simply check the final result against the zero vector to ensure that it found the global minimum I'm looking for?

Comment: Do you have library access to *Numerical Optimization* by Nocedal and Wright (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-0-387-40065-5), start of Chapter 11? Minimizing sum of squared residuals is a common starting point for some algorithms.

Comment: No, but skimming those chapter titles it looks like a book I should probably own.

Comment: and to go from Newton-Raphson-Dogleg solving $f(x) = 0$ you instead just minimize the scalar $Vector.Dot(f(x), f(x))$?  Or do you minimize the vector quantity $(f_x^2) i + (f_y^2) j + (f_z^2) j$?  (not sure what that vector product is called)